# Normalization problem partial dependency,

Tags: database

I'm trying to figure out normalization problem to resolve it to 3NF.

Below is a problem that I have.

```
FeedTheChildrenMinistries (donorID, donorName, childID, childName, countryCode, countryName, countryPopulation, regularMonthlyDonationAmy,  extraDonationTotal)
```

These are the business rules for the problem.

- A donor can sponsor many children for the different donor amount.
- A child can be sponsored by only one donor
- A countryCode and countryName are the child's
- An extra donation for a specific child
- Extra donation total is the total of all extra donations for a specific child for the year
- Each country has a specific name and the population.

I know the donorName and the childName should be breakdown like the form below.

```
donorName (donor_first, donor_last)
childName (child_first, child_last)
```

I'm just not sure about PK, PD, and TD.

Answer (score 0):

This is a logical model of your problem in 5th Normal Form.

[image]

---

This is the T-SQL DDL that you can use to generate your database in SQL Server.

```
/*
T-SQL DDL for the FeedTheChildrenMinistries.
Copyright (C) 2019 Ken Evans, The ORM Foundation.

This is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License Version 3 as published by
the Free Software Foundation.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.
*/


CREATE SCHEMA FeedTheChildrenMinistries

GO

CREATE TABLE FeedTheChildrenMinistries.Donor

(

    donorId int NOT NULL,
    firstName nchar(40) NOT NULL,
    lastName nchar(40) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Donor_PK PRIMARY KEY(donorId)
)

GO


CREATE TABLE FeedTheChildrenMinistries.Child

(

    childId int NOT NULL,
    countryCode nchar(10) NOT NULL,
    firstName nchar(40) NOT NULL,
    lastName nchar(40) NOT NULL,
    donorId int,
    CONSTRAINT Child_PK PRIMARY KEY(childId)
)

GO


CREATE TABLE FeedTheChildrenMinistries.Country

(

    countryCode nchar(10) NOT NULL,
    countryName nchar(100) NOT NULL,
    countryPopulation int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Country_PK PRIMARY KEY(countryCode)
)

GO


CREATE TABLE FeedTheChildrenMinistries.DonorMakesExtraDonationForChild

(

    donorId int NOT NULL,
    extraDonation decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
    childId int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT DonorMakesExtraDonationForChild_PK PRIMARY KEY(donorId, extraDonation)
)

GO


CREATE TABLE FeedTheChildrenMinistries.DonorMakesMonthlyDonationForChild

(

    donorId int NOT NULL,
    monthlyDonation decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
    childId int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT DonorMakesMonthlyDonationForChild_PK PRIMARY KEY(donorId, monthlyDonation)

)

GO


ALTER TABLE FeedTheChildrenMinistries.Child ADD CONSTRAINT Child_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (donorId) REFERENCES FeedTheChildrenMinistries.Donor (donorId) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION

GO


ALTER TABLE FeedTheChildrenMinistries.Child ADD CONSTRAINT Child_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (countryCode) REFERENCES FeedTheChildrenMinistries.Country (countryCode) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION

GO


ALTER TABLE FeedTheChildrenMinistries.DonorMakesExtraDonationForChild ADD CONSTRAINT DonorMakesExtraDonationForChild_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (donorId) REFERENCES FeedTheChildrenMinistries.Donor (donorId) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION

GO


ALTER TABLE FeedTheChildrenMinistries.DonorMakesExtraDonationForChild ADD CONSTRAINT DonorMakesExtraDonationForChild_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (childId) REFERENCES FeedTheChildrenMinistries.Child (childId) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION

GO


ALTER TABLE FeedTheChildrenMinistries.DonorMakesMonthlyDonationForChild ADD CONSTRAINT DonorMakesMonthlyDonationForChild_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (donorId) REFERENCES FeedTheChildrenMinistries.Donor (donorId) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION

GO


ALTER TABLE FeedTheChildrenMinistries.DonorMakesMonthlyDonationForChild ADD CONSTRAINT DonorMakesMonthlyDonationForChild_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (childId) REFERENCES FeedTheChildrenMinistries.Child (childId) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION

GO
```